# present perfect or past simple in this case

Tags: present-perfect

> The English winter **has been** very wet. It **did not snow**, and I
>   don't think it will now, as spring is coming very soon.

I used the present perfect because winter has not finished, but I used past simple because it should have snowed before. Now, it is too late for snowing.

Is the past simple a good choice, or should I have written it as *has not snowed*?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: *winter **has been** very wet = it's still very wet;* *winter **was** very wet = it's no longer wet;* *it **didn't** snow = it didn't happen and it's not going to; it **hasn't** snowed = not yet but it will eventually occur*

Comment: @Ustanak *...but **may** eventually occur.*

Comment: @Ustanak: winter was very wet = it is no longer *winter*; spring may be wet :)

Comment: Does "*As* in England" mean "*Like* in England"? When I read this part, I get "*As/like* in England, winter has been very wet." Then a comma should be used. However I wonder if you meant "*Since* in England winter has been very wet..." but that wouldn't be a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> As in England winter has been very wet. It did not snow and I think it
>   will not now as spring is coming very soon .

*"I used present perfect because winter has not finished but I used past simple because it should have snowed before now it is too late for snowing, is past simple a good choice or should have written it has not snowed."*

If winter is not quite over, as you say, your reason for choosing present perfect **has been wet** is good.

If it is now too late for snow, then your reason for choosing simple past **it did not snow** is also good.  The part of the year when snow is possible is completely behind us.

But if there is still a chance that the "snowy season" is not quite finished, then you could say "it has not snowed". That choice indicates that you consider snow still a possibility.

The choice of tenses reveals our thinking when we speak.

Comment: I would not use just "It did not snow" because it does not have a specific time reference (it could refer to any time before present). I would prefer using "It did not snow *yet*".

Comment: @user3169. There is no need for an explicit time reference.  The past tense would indicate that the speaker believes the time for snow has passed. Adding **yet** would indicate just the opposite.

Comment: The statement made in April could mean "it did not snow (in January)" when January is the primary month when it snows (but then there was some snow in Feb. and March). Maybe I am picking at this though.

Comment: @user3169 : *It did not snow yet* is marginal|ungrammatical. Grammatical would be *It has not snowed yet* or *It had not snowed yet*.  The word **yet** attaches the statement to the speaker's Present, their temporal "origo". If their origo is in the present, we'd use present perfect; if that origo is a point-of-reference in the past, in relation to an earlier past, then we'd use the past perfect.